# Adding new file in content Folder does not work in NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget

I created a package using NuGet C# project with a folder (say Pages) inside content folder having some aspx/aspx.cs files, which are actually part  of another Project and when I am updating the file everything works OK (i.e. when I install/update the package it is also updating).

But I have a requirement: If I am adding a new aspx page say `Search.aspx` inside the same folder (i.e. Pages) from Visual Studio, which I already added in the content folder should also be added in the content Folder, which is not happening.

So, is there any way to update new added Files automatically in the content folder?

Finally, I would like to mention that I want to do it in NuGet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to [Specify Entire Folder for Package Contents](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.2) in your nuspec file. The Nuget.org website has a sample of that but in short, you can add this to the nuspec:

```
<file src="scripts\" target="content\scripts"/>
```